# adjoint of composition of bounded linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Our lecturer said it shouldn't be any problem to prove this on our own, but I must be missing something obvious!

Let $E$, $F$ and $G$ be normed spaces. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$, $S \in \mathcal{L}(F,G)$. Then $(ST)' = T'S'$.

(we define the adjoint of $T$ as $(T'g)(x) = g(Tx)$, where $g \in F'$(the dual of F), $x \in E$)

I've tried looking at it by definition, $((ST)'g)(x) = g((ST)(x))$ but wouldn't know where to go from there.

Any help welcome.

Comment: so would that mean $g \circ S(Tx) = T'(g \circ S)(x)$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. It wouldn't help, I think. But writing $g((ST)(x)) = g(S(Tx))=(S' g)(Tx)$ will.

Answer (score 1):

Er, in your question, $T^{'}$ is from $F^{'}$ to $E^{'}$ while the $S^{'}$ is from $G^{'}$ to $F^{'}$, so $(ST)^{'}=T^{'}S^{'}$ is from $G^{'}$ to $E^{'}$. And you say $((ST)^{'}g_{1})(x)=g_{1}((ST)(x))$ (yes, you are right, it is follows from the definition), but you must notice that $g_{1}\in G^{'}$ because it acts on $ST(x)\in G$.

It is not hard, just be patient to the definitions. :)